# How many times will the statement print(j); be executed. Represented as a Big O function of n

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
     k=0;
     for (j=0; j<n; j=j+k) {
          k=k+1;
          print(j);
     }
}
```

Hello all, I have already done a bit of work on this problem but I feel that Im missing something simple for the answer. I realize that J is increasing in a triangular number series(0,1,3,6,10,15...)so I believe that makes it the variable in the loop that increases the most each loop. Is representing this in a Big O function of n just asking for the time complexity of this loop? If so how do I determine that based on how j is increasing?

Answer (score 0):

As you already noticed, the inner loop variable increases as the [triangular number sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number). For this sequence, we have that the *m*th term a<sub>m</sub> can be expressed as:

*a<sub>m</sub> = m(m + 1)/2*

So, if *j* will go up to *n*, we can solve for the number of iterations *m*:

*m(m + 1)/2 = n*

*m<sup>2</sup> + m - 2n = 0*

The quadratic formula gives that the positive root is:

*m = 1/2 *  √(8n + 1) - 1/2 = O(√n)*

So, since the outer loop clearly runs *O(n)* times, the total time complexity in terms of prints should be *O(n√n)*.